# Easy way to determine Ionic/Cordova plugin support for different mobile Operating Systems?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I'm making an Ionic (3.9.2) application, and have added several plugins over the past few months.  Originally, I was targeting Android 5+ and iOS 10+, but I'm wondering if it's possible to gain even more market share by targeting Android 4.4+ (which [ATTOW will give my app ~93% market share rather than ~82%](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)).

I'm hoping there is a quick/easy way to determine if my existing plugins *should be* (that is, according to the plugin creator) compatible with Android 4.4.

What I'm trying to avoid is having to get that info from each and every plugin's documentation.  E.g. for geolocation, I would visit https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/ and check it's compatibility table, then do the same for a dozen other plugins.

Is there an easier way to check plugin vs. device OS compatibility?  E.g. from the command line, or with the use of another plugin?

(I'm using cordova-android 7.0.0 and cordova-ios 4.5.4)

Answer (score 0):

**No!  There is not.**

That is, ATTOW, it appears that **there is no easy or automatic way to determine mobile device compatibility for your app and its plugins**.

That is, I merely went through each plugin listed in config.xml, googled it, read its documentation, and collected "supported platforms" information into a PLUGINS.txt file in my app's documentation.  E.g.

```
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/
- Cordova Android 4.0.0 or above

cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/
- Android 2.1+   
- Browser
```

I also included some platform compatibility information on [the Cordova platform](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/support/index.html) itself.

```
ATTOW "ionic info" yields:
  global packages:
      cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
  local packages:
      Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.3 ios 4.5.4
      Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```